# Substitute zero for missing values in python

Tags: python, regex, string-parsing

I have a text file with the following entries:

```
 G1 X-387.7 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0 F=R3 
 Y1.824 Z264.663 A3=-1.0 C3=0.0
```

I extracted the numbers(numerical equivalents) of the variable alphabets using the code

```
 import re
 with open('input file.txt','r') as file:
 for line in file:
    print re.findall("(?<=[AZaz])?(?!\d*=)[0-9.+-]+",line)
```

I got the results as follows:

```
   ['-387.7', '-1.0', '0.0', '0.0', '3']
   ['1.824', '264.663', '-1.0', '0.0']
```

But I need only the values corresponding to x,y,z,a3,b3,c3. All other variables should be neglected. How to selectively remove other variables and substitute 0 in the plac of missing variable(x,y,z,a3,b3,c3)?

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do the substitution for missing values?

Comment: You don't even know what you already have.

Comment: I'm asking about the substitution for the x,y,z,a3,b3,c3 missing values in the original sequence

Comment: Your original includes a g1 and an f, and you don't even know which those are.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams they are the values to be neglected/ignored. That is what I mentioned in the question. only the x,,y,z,a3,b3,c3 values need to be considered (rest is ignored). If any of the x,y,z,a3,b3,c3 values are missing then how to substitute 0 in its place?

Comment: But if you don't know where they are then how can you know what to do with them?

Comment: Are you trying to parse gcode?

Comment: @Blender yes. I did the parsing. Is there a way to substitute for the missing values as I explained below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will match the numbers immediately after X, Y, Z, A3, B3 and C3. If any of the strings in the `required` list are missing from the input, it will set them to `0.0`.

```
required = ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A3=', 'B3=', 'C3=']    
matches = re.findall(r"(X|Y|Z|A3=|B3=|C3=)(\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)", line)

for var in required:
    if var not in [v for v, val in matches]:
        matches.append((var, '0.0'))
```

Sample input: `G1 X-387.7 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0 F=R3` (Y and Z are missing)

Result:

```
[('X', '-387.7'), ('A3=', '-1.0'), ('B3=', '0.0'), ('C3=', '0.0'), ('Y', '0.0'), ('Z', '0.0')]
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/CEUCpU/4

Comment: By selective removal of other variables, I mean, to get the numbers immediately following x,y,z and a3,b3,c3. Your regex works perfectly. Thanks! Is there a way t0 substitute a float value 0.0 in the place of missing x,y,z ,a3,b3,c3?  To be more precise the result sequence should have 6 values for each of the 6 alphabets

Comment: By missing, do you mean inputs like this? `G1 X A3= B3= C3= F=R3`?

Comment: No, for example, `G1 X-387.7 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0 F=R3` in this line y and z are missing and I need the result to be as follows `'-387.7', '0.0', '0.0', '-1.0', '0.0', '0.0'`

Comment: @DaphFab I've edited my answer to account for missing values

Comment: This works !! But the result is displayed as coordinates according to your code. I just need the numerical value in the form of  `'-387.7', '0.0', '0.0', '-1.0', '0.0', '0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of getting what you want from each text line. I've specified that (+/-) decimals after x,y,z or A3,B3,C3 should be selected.

```
import re
file = "/path/to/text.txt"
with open(file,'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print(line)
        print(re.findall("[XYZABC3=](-?\d+\.\d+)", line))
```

Prints as follows:

```
G1 X-387.7 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0 F=R3 

['-387.7', '-1.0', '0.0', '0.0']

 Y1.824 Z264.663 A3=-1.0 C3=0.0

['1.824', '264.663', '-1.0', '0.0']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using a regex here and just parse it with string manipulations:

```
def read_commands(data):
    last_command = []

    for token in data.split():
        if token.startswith('G') and token[1:].isnumeric():
            if last_command:
                yield last_command

            last_command = [token]
        else:
            last_command.append(token)

    yield last_command


def parse_command(command):
    code = command[0]
    args = {}

    for arg in command[1:]:
        if '=' in arg:
            key, value = arg.split('=')
        else:
            key = arg[0]
            value = arg[1:]

        args[key] = value

    return code, args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = '''
        G1 X-387.7 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0 F=R3 
        Y1.824 Z264.663 A3=-1.0 C3=0.0


        G1 X-387.7 A3=-1.0 B3=0.0 C3=0.0 F=R3 Y1.824 Z264.663 A3=-1.0 C3=0.0

        G1 X0 Y0 Z0
    '''

    for command in read_commands(data):
        code, args = parse_command(command)

        print(args.get('A3', 0))
```

Comment: your code is written only for the 2 sample lines that I mentioned. I have a file with 100 such lines

Comment: @DaphFab: I'm not going to write an entire gcode parser. This is enough to parse gcode files without comments. You can add in support for other code types easily.

Comment: agreed. You have mentioned the specific 2 input lines in your code. While doing it for the entire file how should it be replaced?

Comment: @DaphFab: Nothing needs to be modified unless your file contains gcode commands that don't start with `G` or comments.